# How to re-position the scatter plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, scatter-plot, axis

This [image] has my current plot and what I want it to be.

The original plot is a bit inside to my liking (axis labels are present for my current plot). I want my plot and the axes lines to be enlarged but the width and height of the plot to be same (axis labels not present).

Thanks!

Tried using different variations for plot margins but didn't work for me

Edit: Adding my code. A basic df with three columns (VA, VF, image_link). Plotting images as scatter points.

```
plot <- ggplot(df_noemp, aes(x = VA, y = VF, image = image_link)) +
  geom_image(aes(image = image_link), size = 0.05, by = "height", asp = 1.33) + 
  labs(
    x = paste0("<br><br><span style='font-size: 14pt'>abcd</span><br><span style='font-size: 11pt'>abcd</span>"),
    y = paste0("<span style='font-size: 14pt'>abcd</span><br><span style='font-size: 11pt'>abcd</span><br>"),
    title = paste0("<br><span style='font-size: 17pt'>abcd</span><br><span style='font-size: 9pt'>abcd</span><br><br><br>")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-150, 60))+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-70, 70)) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(linetype = "dashed", color = "#fafafa"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "#2e2e2e", size = 10.9, family = "Tw Cen MT"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#2e2e2e", size = 10.9, family = "Tw Cen MT"),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown(angle = 0, face = "bold", family = "Trebuchet MS"),
    plot.caption = ggtext::element_markdown(margin = margin(t = 20), size = 6, family = "Trebuchet MS"),
    plot.background = element_rect(color = NA, fill = "#f5f5f5"),
    axis.line.x = element_line(color="#2e2e2e", size = 0.6),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color="#2e2e2e", size = 0.6),
    axis.title.x = ggtext::element_markdown(angle = 0, face = "bold", family = "Tw Cen MT"),
    axis.title.y = ggtext::element_markdown(angle = 90, face = "bold", family = "Tw Cen MT"),
    aspect.ratio = 1/1.33
  )  


ggsave(
  "var-asp-theme.png", plot, 
  # make the width equivalent to the aspect.ratio
  height = 9, width = 8, dpi = "retina"
)
```

```
DF looks like this

VA   VF   image_link
1    2    path_one
2    4    path_two
and so on
```

Edit 2: Somehow stumbled upon the answer myself, but came another issue. Firstly, just used more variations for plot_margin and stumbled upon the right one. But my x-axis is limited. [image].

Anyone know how do I extend the x-axis line but maintaining the original breaks? I have tried using breaks and limits but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please provide code for generating that plot. I recognize you are blanking out the content; you can use fake data to be somewhat representative of your real data so that your plot code can be shared. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans Hey, sorry for that, just added the code. As mentioned, nothing too extraordinary df.  Just three columns and one of them has image links which I'm gonna use as scatter points.

Comment: I'm assuming `ggimage` as well

Comment: yes, used ggimage here

Comment: hey @r2evans, i somehow got the solution to my original question but came upon a new one. was hoping if you could look into it and maybe you help me here. thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "extend the x-axis"? have you tried either of `scale_x_continuous(limits=..., breaks=...)`?

Comment: @r2evans, I have uploaded a new image that shows the x-axis being a little shorter. I have used both limits and breaks, but doesn't seem to work.